# ggplot removes data when trying to change point colors and /or shapes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a simple point estimate with confidence interval plot. I can get it to plot as I'd like until I try to change the point shape and/or the color.  When I try to change either I get "Warning: Removed 4 rows containing missing values (geom_point)." and end up with a blank plot.

I've checked out and tried the suggestions on:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549463/the-meaning-of-warning-message-removed-4-rows-containing-missing-values-geom-p)
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045476/why-does-r-say-that-there-are-rows-containing-missing-values)
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505298/explain-ggplot2-warning-removed-k-rows-containing-missing-values)
[and here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/geom-errorbar-issue-in-ggplot2-td4706297.html)
 and a couple other places but to no avail.

A Reproducible Example

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)

# Create some sample data 

point_est <- 4:1
se        <- runif(4)

df <- data.frame(point_est = point_est,
                 se        = se,
                 lower     = point_est - se,
                 upper     = point_est + se,
                 year      = c("c", "c", "p", "p"),
                 group     = letters[1:4])

group_names <- paste0("Display Name for \n Group ", LETTERS[1:4])
names(group_names) <- letters[1:4]

legend_text <- c("Previous Year Rate with 95% Confidence Intervals",
                 "Current Year Rate with 95% Confidence Intervals")
names(legend_text) <- c("p", "c")

df$year = factor(df$year, levels = names(legend_text), labels = legend_text)
df$group = factor(df$group, levels = names(group_names), labels = group_names)

# Plot looks good except the colors and shape of the points need changing
ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = point_est, color = year, label= year, shape = year)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), width=.3) +
  geom_point(size = 3.2) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*3, name = "This is my Right Axis")) +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = "This is my Left Axis") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

```r
# now change the shapes of the points and the colors of the error bars
shapes <- c(17, 15)
names(shapes) <- names(legend_text)

colors <- c("pink", "blue")
names(colors) <- names(legend_text)

ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = point_est, color = year, label= year, shape = year)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), width=.3) +
  geom_point(size = 3.2) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*3, name = "This is my Right Axis")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = shapes) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colors) +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = "This is my Left Axis") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA),
        panel.background = element_blank()) 
#> Warning: Removed 4 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

```r
# Blank plot now and warnings:(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you used `names(legend_text)` rather than `legend_text` as the names of your `shapes` and `colors` vectors. `legend_text` is what matches the values in the `year` column of your data. Do `names(colors) <- legend_text` and likewise for `shapes` and the plot will work. Nothing was plotted because the names of the `colors` and `shapes` vectors did not match any of the levels of `df$year`, so no colors or shapes were assigned for the actual values in `year`.

It looks like maybe you got tripped up by `levels` vs. `labels` in the `factor` function. By default, the `levels` are the existing set of unique values in the data and the `labels` are set equal to the levels. However, if you include a `labels` argument in `factor`, the data values get relabeled to be the values in the `labels` argument.

To make this concrete, note in the code below that the names of the `shapes` and `colors` vectors are `p` and `c`, which is different from the values in `df$year`.

> ```
> > df[ , "year", drop=FALSE]
>                                               year
> 1  Current Year Rate with 95% Confidence Intervals
> 2  Current Year Rate with 95% Confidence Intervals
> 3 Previous Year Rate with 95% Confidence Intervals
> 4 Previous Year Rate with 95% Confidence Intervals
>
> > levels(df$year)
> [1] "Previous Year Rate with 95% Confidence Intervals" "Current Year Rate with 95% Confidence Intervals"
>
>
> > shapes
>  p  c 
> 17 15 
> > colors
>      p      c 
> "pink" "blue"
> ```

Comment: and Mike Thanks for the help.  This works with one exception on my actual data.  Say df is now subset to just the current year data.  The plot is correct except the legend only contains the current year.  I'd like the legend to still show both levels and have all 4 groups even though 2 of the groups will be empty.

Comment: You can add `drop=FALSE` to the `scale_***_manual` calls, just as with the `scale_x_discrete` call.

Comment: I was an idiot.  I did that for the x axis categories but forgot that wasn't for the legend also.  Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the vectors directly into the ggplot it will work. 
For scale_shape_manual put c(17,15) for the values and for scale_color_manual put c("Pink","Blue") for the values. Or just do not assign names to the shapes and colors vectors. That is what it is throwing it off.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = point_est, color = year, label= year, shape = year)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), width=.3) +
  geom_point(size = 3.2) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*3, name = "This is my Right Axis")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(17, 15)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("pink", "blue")) +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = "This is my Left Axis") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA),
        panel.background = element_blank()) 



######if you want to use the vectors do not name them 
shapes <- c(17, 15)

colors <- c("pink", "blue")

ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = point_est, color = year, label= year, shape = year)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), width=.3) +
  geom_point(size = 3.2) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*3, name = "This is my Right Axis")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = shapes) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colors) +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = "This is my Left Axis") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```